# Pulling all logs from various servers to excel - Having trouble pulling extra logs

Tags: powershell

For the last day, I have been working on a script to pull logs from various servers. I have found a script that does this and I have built on it.

So far I can pull application and system logs. However, I am having trouble pulling security logs. If I run the `Get-EventLog Security` it works fine on its own, but when I try adding to my script below it does not pull the logs.

```
Set-Variable -Name EventAgeDays -Value 7    #takes events for the latest 7 days - change the number as required
Set-Variable -Name CompArr -Value @("Serv1, serv2, serv3")   # replace it with the server names - FOR TESTING I HAVE USED MY MACHINE NAME
Set-Variable -Name LogNames -Value @("Application", "System")  # Checking app logs, system logs and security logs
Set-Variable -Name EventTypes -Value @("Error", "Warning")  # Loading only Errors and Warnings
Set-Variable -Name ExportFolder -Value "C:\test.csv" # Create excel file called "test"

$mLog_c = @()   #consolidated error log

$now       = Get-Date
$startdate = $now.AddDays(-$EventAgeDays)

# creates .csv file with the date and time when the script was run on
# the end of "test.csv"
$ExportFile = $ExportFolder + "Log" + $now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy---hh-mm-ss") + ".csv"

foreach ($comp in $CompArr) {
    foreach ($el in $LogNames) {
        Write-Host Processing $comp\$log
        $el = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $comp -Log $log -After $startdate -EntryType $EventTypes
        $el_c += $el  #consolidating
    }
}

$log_sorted = $el_c | Sort-Object TimeGenerated    #sort by time

Write-Host Exporting to $ExportFile

$log_sorted |
    Select Date, ServerName, EntryType, TimeGenerated, Source, EventID,
           PID, TID, Component, message |
    Export-Csv $ExportFile -NoTypeInfo  #EXPORT COMMAND

Write-Host Completed #Completed once finished
```

Comment: Please show the code that *isn't* working, including all errors you're getting from *that* code.

Comment: Hi Ansgar - for set variable 3rd line down. If i put  "Application", "System", "Security"  I get the following error

Comment: get-eventlog : No matches found

At line:18 char:11

+     $el = get-eventlog -ComputerName $comp -log $log -After $startdat ...

+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-EventLog], ArgumentException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetEventLogNoEntriesFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand